# How to print found data from file in 2byte array

Tags: python-3.x

i want to get data that i got as a result displayed like 312d 3036 2d30 3706 5814 0847 4831 3033 3733 3930 like it would be if i opened it in hex editor i have tryed to do it by codeing/decodeing but with no success.

here is the code i made that finds the strings i want:

```
    import re
import struct

file = open ("eeprom", "rb") .read().hex()
DTC_data = re.search("ffff30(.*)100077", file)
DTC_data_final = print (DTC_data.group(1))

#finds string between two strings in 2nd line of eeprom file

switch_data = re.search("010607(.*)313132", file)
switch_data_final = print (switch_data.group(1))

#finds string betwenn two strings in 3rd line of eeprom file
```

Result i get is

```
312d30362d3037065814
08474831303337333930
```

Comment: What are you actually asking? Your question seems to be two completely unrelated things.

Comment: i want to get data that i got as a result displayed like 312d 3036 2d30 3706 5814
0847 4831 3033 3733 3930 like it would be if i opened it in hex editor

Comment: You should make that part of your question